# Download HTML String content in android

Tags: android

I have String with html format, not url, that send through from api. Those include image and bootstrap css. I would like to download those things to show in offline including image and css to show right format.

Is there any library to download html string content?

Comment: get String and pass it to webview it will load that Data in form of web ?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi yes. but no idea how to download that html string context when I got data from api.

Comment: are you getting Json.?

Answer (score 0):

All You Have to do is get your `Json` Data convert `Json` to String `json.toString();`
and pass it to `data=json.String();`
and check if data is already stored or not in `Shared Preferences`

```
 DataBaseHelper DB;
     if(DB.getHTMLStoredData(context)){
    data=DB.getHTMLStoredData(context)
    }else{
    data=json.String();
    }

    //data == html data which you want to load 
         WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
         webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Then how can you show back to user if they are offline?

Comment: Store it in Shared preference or database.?

Comment: store in SD card. but store file directory in database.

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. Above code  will not save image, css or javascript  those include in html string.

Comment: it will store every thing!

Comment: and you use them as well..for offline try to read it from file as well.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159040/discussion-between-atif-abbasi-and-sai-aung-myint-soe).